# cfsavecontent from CFML to cfscript

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I'm trying to write a savecontent in cfscript.

I have it in CFML:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="errortext">
    <cfoutput>
        An error occurred: http://#cgi.server_name##cgi.script_name#?#cgi.query_string#<br />
        Time: #dateFormat(now(), "short")# #timeFormat(now(), "short")#<br />

        <cfdump var="#session#" label="Session">
        <cfdump var="#error#" label="Error">
        <cfdump var="#form#" label="Form">
        <cfdump var="#url#" label="URL">

    </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
```

I need it in cfscript, but how can I do it? Can I put everything inside WriteOuput()?

Thanks

Example not working:

```
<cfscript>
  local.test = "TEST";
  local.OK = "OK";
  savecontent variable="contentViaScript" {
    writeOutput(
      "String Message:  <br />"
      writeDump(local);
    );
  }
  writeOutput(contentViaScript);
</cfscript>

<cfdump var = '#contentViaScript#' />
```

Comment: Read this:  http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/03/how-about-this-for-savecontent.html

Comment: I tried it already, and it did not work

Comment: What part didn't work?

Comment: WriteDump() inside writeOutput()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to wrap `writedump` in `writeoutput`.

```
<cfscript>
  local.test = "TEST";
  local.OK = "OK";
  savecontent variable="contentViaScript" {
    writeOutput("String Message:  <br />");
    writeDump(local);
  }
  writeOutput(contentViaScript);
</cfscript>

<cfdump var = '#contentViaScript#' />
```

[**DEMO**](https://www.trycf.com/gist/bbf2edd28beac3b8d450b0e5301bb042/acf?theme=monokai)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<cfscript>
  local.test = "TEST";
  local.OK = "OK";
  savecontent variable="contentViaScript" {
    writeOutput(
      "String Message:  <br />
      #writeDump(local)#"
    );
  }
  writeOutput(contentViaScript);
</cfscript>

<cfdump var = '#contentViaScript#' />
```